# C++ Segmentation error(core dumped)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, avl-tree

So the problem I'm having is a segmentation error. 
I'm trying to implement an AVLtree, and I believe that this part of my code is the problem, but I can't pinpoint what I've done wrong.

Part of my AVLtree class:

```
  Node* AVLtree::findNode(string cityID){
       Node *thisNode = this->rootNode;
       while(thisNode!=0){
            if(thisNode->getCity()->getName().compare(cityID)==0){return thisNode;
            }else if(thisNode->getChildR()->getCity()->getName() < cityID){ thisNode = thisNode->getChildR();
            }else{thisNode = thisNode->getChildL();}
       }
  return this->rootNode;
  }
```

My main file:

```
     int main(){
     ....
     City city1("BoomTown", "EU", 1.01, 2.02); 
     ....
     AVLtree avltree1(&city1);
     cout<< "TEST 1: AVLtree with city paramter of city1 (" << city1.getName()<< ")" << endl;
     cout << "TEST 2: Getting name of city1: " << avltree1.findNode("BoomTown")->getCity()->getName() << endl;
```

My City class and Node classes both work, and I can create an AVLtree. I just can't seem to find a node within it.

Here is my output:

```
    $ ./mainTest
    TEST 1: AVLtree with city paramter of city1 (BoomTown)
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm sorry if this is a simple error, but I'm new to C++ and takes time and practice to learn :)
Thanks in advance.

(p.s. If you need any more code please ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code it seems you check if the current node is null but you don't check if the children node is null before accessing it:

```
while(thisNode!=0) {
    // ... 
    if(thisNode->getChildR()->getCity()->getName() < cityID){
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
                 here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've sorted it now by making sure that it checks that the  nodes aren't empty.
Again, thanks!

Comment: @Student38068: the proper fix is probably _not_ to look at the child nodes at this point anyway! You want to decide which way to go based on `thisNode->getCity()->getName()`: If this is the sought name, you have found the node. If the name is bigger than the sought city you go down the left side, otherwise you go down the right side!

Comment: So, would it be something like this? 
        Node *thisNode = this->rootNode;
        while(thisNode!=0){
            if(thisNode==0){break;} // For when thisNode is empty.
            int location = thisNode->getCity()->getName().compare(cityID);
            if(location==0){return thisNode;
            }else if(location>0){thisNode = thisNode->getChildR();
            }else{thisNode->getChildL();}  
      }`code`

Comment: @Student38068: This is more like it normally look like! I think with your approach nodes in the left subtree of the right child node can't be reached.

Comment: @Student38068: sorry, there was an _original_ missing: with the original code in the question, you wouldn't look at the left subtree of the right child (draw a picture of a tree where the left child of the root's right child has the name you look for: you wouldn't go there with your original code; you would go there with the modified code, I think).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. It would bypass the right-left subtree as there would be a right-right subtree. 
Once again, thanks! Just a process of trial and error to learn I suppose! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably connected with you not checking if your methods return a propper pointer. If you try to invoke a method on an invalid pointer, you'll bget an segmentation error.

In your case:
if `thisNode->getChildR()` doesn't actually return a valid pointer, calling `getCity()` makes the core dump.